# Problemas com uint64_t em C++

Tags: c, c++

Estou com problema com números muito grandes. Quando coloco a entrada 
`64` o meu programa não exibe a resposta certa, lembrando que todos os números menores estão com a saída normal.

Saída do programa:

0 kg

Saída esperada:

1537228672809129 kg

código fonte:

```
#include <iostream>    
using namespace std;



int main(){

    int a;
    uint64_t x=1,kg;
    cin>>a;
    for(int cont=0;cont<a;cont++){
        x*=2.0;
    }
    kg=x/12/1000;
    cout<<kg<<" kg\n";




}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vai ter que usar uma biblioteca de `BigInteger` ou criar uma própria. Cada uma tem suas vantagens e desvantagens. Escolhi a [InfInt](https://sercantutar.github.io/infint/) por ser simples de pegar e usar, mas ela não tem uma função ou operador de exponenciação, o que poderia eliminar este laço. Mas pelo menos funciona:

```
int a;
cin >> a;
InfInt x = 1, kg;
for (int cont = 0; cont < a; cont++) {
    x *= 2;
}
kg = x / 12000;
cout << kg << " kg\n";
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/U09n0h). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/jdmbnkop-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Typing/BigInt.cpp).